# GROUP BY datetime with a timeshift

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

The following statement gives me the average wind speed and total production for each day, grouped by site ID and plant number.

```
SELECT STE_ID, PNT_NO, T_SMP, AVG(AVR_WS), SUM(AVR_PW) FROM argosrecord GROUP BY STE_ID , PNT_NO , YEAR(T_SMP) , MONTH(T_SMP) , DAY(T_SMP)
```

I would like to adapt this query to calculate the average and sum from 2am to 2am instead of midnight to midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select STE_ID,
    PNT_NO,
    YEAR(dateadd(hour, -2, T_SMP)) as Year,
    MONTH(dateadd(hour, -2, T_SMP)) as Month,
    DAY(dateadd(hour, -2, T_SMP)) as Day,
    AVG(AVR_WS) as AVG_AVR_WS,
    SUM(AVR_PW) as SUM_AVR_PW
from argosrecord
group by STE_ID,
    PNT_NO,
    YEAR(dateadd(hour, -2, T_SMP)),
    MONTH(dateadd(hour, -2, T_SMP)),
    DAY(dateadd(hour, -2, T_SMP))
```

For those using MySQL :

```
select 
    STE_ID,
    PNT_NO,
    T_SMP,
    avg(AVR_WS),
    sum(AVR_PW)
FROM
    argosrecord
GROUP BY 
    STE_ID , 
    PNT_NO , 
    YEAR(DATE_ADD(T_SMP, INTERVAL -2 HOUR)) , 
    MONTH(DATE_ADD(T_SMP, INTERVAL -2 HOUR)) , 
    DAY(DATE_ADD(T_SMP, INTERVAL -2 HOUR))
```

Comment: @klonq Thanks, I missed the mysql tag.